# Integrating the Office 365 and/or Windows Live credentials in to our website like FB and Twitter

Tags: plugins

I have a requirements like this, Integrating the Office 365 logins or Windows Live logins in to our website, means like Facebook and Twitter I will show one button on login page, onclick of that button user needs to redirect to Office 365 login page and needs to fill the login details. After successful authentication user need to redirect back to the site and register to our site as a user. I tried to find API for Office 365 but couldn't able to find any.

This is for WordPress website, I found [WPOffice 365](https://wpoffice365.com/product/azure-ad-user-authentication-wordpress/), but I have a confusion here that is, will it work for all Office 365 credentials?

One of my friend used this plugin, but he said, he tried many ways but he stuck with configuring the AAD APP and he is continuously getting this error with that plugin. And WPOffice 365 support is paid.

> ERROR: Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.

And I found [Auth0](https://auth0.com/), but I didn't find Office 365 in their providers list.

Can any one have any idea to integrate Office 365 in to our application?

Thanks in advance and any help here is much appreciated.

Comment: Auth0 https://wordpress.org/plugins/auth0/ works on Office365."Auth0 allows multiple authentication providers. You can have social providers like Facebook, Twitter, Google+, etc., you can have a database of users/passwords (just like WordPress but hosted in Auth0) or you can use an Enterprise directory like Active Directory, LDAP, Office365, SAML and others."

Answer (score 0):

You can use Auth0 wordpress.org/plugins/auth0 plugin for any microsoft products. “Extra settings” that allows you to add a json object with all the settings you want to configure. By using this plugin you are delegating the site authentication to Auth0. That means that you won’t be using the WordPress database to authenticate users anymore and the default WP login box won’t show anymore.

Comment: Hi Nuno, thanks for your response, I tried with Auth0 and WPOffice365 plugins. When I use the Auth0 by creating the Microsoft Azure Active Directory I'm getting this error _myapp needs permission to access resources in your organisation that only an admin can grant. Please ask an admin to grant permission to this app before you can use it_ I'm the owner of this app and I have given permission to all required things still I stuck with this.